# Fetch rows based on the highest value of a column and criteria on another column

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, self-join

I'm looking for an SQL query that gives a Scr for each user, from the highest Seq, where the Scr is not equal to 0. It is guaranteed that the Seq values are unique for each User.

**Sample data:**

```
ID  Cde User    Scr Seq
1   1   James   110 19
2   1   James   85  20
3   1   James   99  21
4   1   James   99  22
5   1   James   0   23
6   2   Andrew  88  19
7   2   Andrew  88  20
8   2   Andrew  88  21
9   2   Andrew  0   22
10  2   Andrew  0   23
11  3   David   0   19
12  3   David   95  20
13  3   David   95  21
14  3   David   0   22
15  3   David   0   23
```

**Query results:**

```
ID  Cde User    Scr Seq
4   1   James   99  22
8   2   Andrew  88  21
13  3   David   95  21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the largest `seq` inside the subquery.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [user], max(seq) MaxSeq
            FROM tablename
            WHERE Scr <> 0
            Group By [user]
        ) b 
            ON a.[user] = b.[user] AND
               a.seq = b.maxSeq
ORDER BY ID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34198/3)

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly and it's useful to have an alternative that doesn't use a transact-sql specific function.

Answer (score 1):

With the row_number() function, you can identify the rows that have this condition, where score is not 0 and ordered by seq in descending order:

```
select ID, Cde, User, Scr, Seq
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by seq desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where scr <> 0
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

(I assume "scr" is the score.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @t table([ID] int, [Cde] int, [User] varchar(6), [Scr] int, [Seq] int);

INSERT INTO @t([ID], [Cde], [User], [Scr], [Seq])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'James', 110, 19),
    (2, 1, 'James', 85, 20),
    (3, 1, 'James', 99, 21),
    (4, 1, 'James', 99, 22),
    (5, 1, 'James', 0, 23),
    (6, 2, 'Andrew', 88, 19),
    (7, 2, 'Andrew', 88, 20),
    (8, 2, 'Andrew', 88, 21),
    (9, 2, 'Andrew', 0, 22),
    (10, 2, 'Andrew', 0, 23),
    (11, 3, 'David', 0, 19),
    (12, 3, 'David', 95, 20),
    (13, 3, 'David', 95, 21),
    (14, 3, 'David', 0, 22),
    (15, 3, 'David', 0, 23);

Select [ID], [Cde], [User], [Scr], [Seq] From 
(Select Rn = Row_Number()Over(Partition By [User] Order By Seq Desc,[User]) , *
From @t 
Where Scr <> 0) x Where x.Rn = 1 Order By 5 Desc,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a self-join. You can use the `row_number` function to select the highest `seq` for each user:

```
select ID, Cde, User, Scr, Seq from  (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by Cde order by Seq desc) rownum
   from tableName where scr <> 0
) a
where a.rownum=1
```

This must be done with an inner query because `row_number()` is only valid in the `select`, not in the `where`.

Comment: hi sir, add this in your subquery `where scr <> 0`